# How can I add these 3 chains horizontally before a section?

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, horizontal-alignment, tikz-chains, pgfornament

I have added a background image in my document and also added pgfornaments in the borders of the document. But the texts aren't starting from the proper place. Also, I am trying to add five horizontally placed small circles of ornaments before a section. But I don't know how to define its place and how to control its size. I am following CTAN's tutorial and writing according to it.
The ornament's chain is also starting from the wrong place.
Here are my codes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}

\title{abc}
\author{saad}
\date{12-12-12}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper, verbose, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage{titling}%



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{A section A Section A Section A Section}


\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.2,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{bright 2.png}};


\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, start chain, node distance=-2mm]
    \node (nworn) [shift={(5mm,-5mm)}, anchor=north west, on chain ] at (current page.north west) {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,17}
      \node [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \node (neorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,24}
      \node [continue chain=going below, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \node (seorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,17}
      \node [continue chain=going left, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \node (sworn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,24}
      \node [continue chain=going above, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=circle placed %
{at=(\tikzchaincount*30:2)}]
\foreach \i in {1,...,12} \node [on chain]%
{\pgfornament[width=1cm]{4}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=circle placed %
{at=(\tikzchaincount*30:2)}]
\foreach \i in {1,...,12} \node [on chain]%
{\pgfornament[width=0.8cm]{4}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=circle placed %
{at=(\tikzchaincount*30:2)}]
\foreach \i in {1,...,12} \node [on chain]%
{\pgfornament[width=1cm]{4}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\section{A Section A Section A Section}

\clearpage
text
\end{document}
```

here is the result
[image: resulting document]

I know almost nothing about placing these chains and controlling their size.
So can anyone describe the solution?

Comment: i removed the background image since i do not have the png file--also removed the geometry since there is a clash as it is repeated twice

Comment: Sorry,I am wanting it horizontally

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}

\title{abc}
\author{saad}
\date{12-12-12}

%\usepackage[paper=a4paper, verbose, centering]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage{titling}%



\begin{document}
    \maketitle
        \vspace*{1cm}
    \section{A section A Section A Section A Section}

    
    
%   
%   \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \node[opacity=0.2,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{bright 2.png}};
%   
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, start chain, node distance=-2mm]
        \node (nworn) [shift={(5mm,-5mm)}, anchor=north west, on chain ] at (current page.north west) {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
        \foreach \i in {1,...,17}
        \node [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
        \node (neorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
        \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
        \node [continue chain=going below, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
        \node (seorn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
        \foreach \i in {1,...,17}
        \node [continue chain=going left, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
        \node (sworn) [on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
        \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
        \node [continue chain=going above, on chain] {\pgfornament[width=10mm]{7}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=circle placed %
        {at=(\tikzchaincount*30:2)}]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,12} \node [on chain]%
        {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{4}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=circle placed %
        {at=(\tikzchaincount*30:2)}]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,12} \node [on chain]%
        {\pgfornament[width=0.8cm]{4}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=circle placed %
        {at=(\tikzchaincount*30:2)}]
        \foreach \i in {1,...,12} \node [on chain]%
        {\pgfornament[width=1cm]{4}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \section{A Section A Section A Section}
    
    \clearpage
    text
\end{document}
h
```

Comment: The OP wants the chain horizontally, smaller and before the section.

Comment: I actually edited and it was my mistake as I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @js bibra, thank you.